# Windows 7: Windows Photo Viewer does not work

Tags: windows-7, photos, rundll32.exe, windows-photo-viewer

After I changed the `ProgramFilesDir` to `D:\Program Files` manually, the Windows Photo Viewer did not work again.

It failed to start with error messagebox `Rundll: could not found D:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll`.

How could I get my photo viewer work without reverting the `ProgramFilesDir`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you browse to the directory and run the exe from there does it work?

Comment: There is no exe files.

Comment: Some windows elements need to reside on the system volume - this may be one of them

Answer (score 1):

You might have moved your `Program Files` folder to `D:`, but left `Windows` folder on drive `C:`. If so, it's not going to work. Ever.

From [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111006-00/?p=9453):

> Now that NTFS is mandatory for the system volume (it took only 13 years to get there!), Windows itself can start taking advantage of NTFS features.
>
> A large percentage of the files installed by Windows are hard-linked to copies in the `C:\Windows\WinSxS` directory. ...and in Windows 7, the two copies of Notepad are now hard links to each other.
>
> Ah, but one of the limitations of hard links is that they cannot span volumes. Some of the hard links out of the WinSxS directory point into places like `C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe`, and this in turn requires that the Program Files directory be on the same volume as your Windows directory.
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience.

PhotoViewer can probably no longer find its required files, because you moved them.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

If you **did** move `Windows` folder to drive `D:`, then this answer doesn't apply to you.